# Generating menu items from JSON file in Android

Tags: java, android

By reading a JSON file from a local folder, Im trying to generate drawer menu having child items. `readJsonDataFromFile();` returns the JSON string. Im using the following code to generate menu.

```
    lstChild = new TreeMap<>();

            try {
                String jsonDataString = readJsonDataFromFile();
                JSONArray menuItemsJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);

                for (int i = 0; i < menuItemsJsonArray.length(); ++i) {
                    JSONObject menuItemObject = menuItemsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String catName = menuItemObject.getString("cname");

                    JSONArray scatJsonArray = new JSONArray(menuItemObject.getString("csubcat"));
                    for (int j = 0; j < scatJsonArray.length(); ++j) {
                        JSONObject scatItemObject = scatJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

                        //********GENERATING CHILD ITEMS HERE***********

                    }
                    lstChild.put(catName,childItem);
                }

            } catch (IOException | JSONException exception) {
                Log.e(HomeActivity.class.getName(), "Unable to parse JSON file.",exception);
            }
  lstTitle = new ArrayList<>(lstChild.keySet());
```

I want to generate child items (**childItem**) and expected record set is like

```
List<String> childItem = Arrays.asList("Beginner","Intermediate","Advanced","Professional");
```

**JSON string**

```
[
  {
    "cid": "1",
    "cname": "WATCHES",
    "cimg": "074321.png",
    "csubcat": [
      {
        "sid": "1",
        "sname": "FASTTRACK"
      },
      {
        "sid": "2",
        "sname": "TIMEX"
      },
      {
        "sid": "3",
        "sname": "ROADSTER"
      },
      {
        "sid": "4",
        "sname": "TITAN"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Im beginner to Android/Java. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post JSON file?

Comment: Added JSON @VinayRathod

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    String jsonDataString = readJsonDataFromFile();
    JSONArray menuItemsJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);

    for (int i = 0; i < menuItemsJsonArray.length(); ++i) {
        JSONObject menuItemObject = menuItemsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String catName = menuItemObject.getString("cname");

        JSONArray scatJsonArray = new JSONArray(menuItemObject.getString("csubcat"));
        List<String> childItem = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < scatJsonArray.length(); ++j) {
            JSONObject scatItemObject = scatJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            childItem.add(scatItemObject. getString("sname"));
        }
        lstChild.put(catName,childItem);
    }
} catch (IOException | JSONException exception) {
    Log.e(HomeActivity.class.getName(), "Unable to parse JSON file.",exception);
}
```

Comment: see logcat and check why app is crashed

Comment: App crashes.. childitem expecting List<String> childItem = Arrays.asList("FASTTRACK","TIMEX","ROADSTER","TITAN");

Comment: can you paste your logcat?

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
Invalid index 2, size is 2
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.xx.xx.Adapter.CustomExpandableListAdapter.getChild(CustomExpandableListAdapter.java:44)
at com.xx.xx.Adapter.CustomExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(CustomExpandableListAdapter.java:77)

Comment: its looks like your list is generated but it crash in `CustomExpandableListAdapter` please check in CustomExpandableListAdapter file line no 44, you don't know how to check error.. my code is works perfect..